# Embed all video in universal HTML5 video player

Tags: php, html, video, embed

I search a system to embed all media in universal video player as :

- Twitter videos
- Facebook videos
- Youtube videos
- Vimeo videos
- etc...

Have you got an idea to embed this in PHP or HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic HTML5 video tag. Here is a very good link to get you started
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

```
<video controls>
  <source src="devstories.webm" 
          type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
  <source src="devstories.mp4"
          type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```

In the example above you can see the video file name is devstories and you can have the following types of video format, mp4, webm and ogg.

If you need more info about the formats you can read up here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 1):

Youtube, Fb or Vimeo doesn't let you push them in other players than its own, but this embeds video from a url in its native player. Haven't studied twitter videos, but you can extend my script. (The function `getvidinfo` also gets thumbnails, but i didn't find how to get one from fb).

```
<?
function getYoutubeIdFromUrl($url) {    
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if(($parts["host"]=="m.youtube.com" || $parts["host"]=="youtube.com" || $parts["host"]=="www.youtube.com" || $parts["host"]=="youtu.be" || $parts["host"]=="www.youtu.be") && !strstr($url,"/c/") && !strstr($url,"/channel/") && !strstr($url,"/user/")){
    if(isset($parts['query'])){
        parse_str($parts['query'], $qs);
        if(isset($qs['v'])){
            return $qs['v'];
        }else if(isset($qs['vi'])){
            return $qs['vi'];
        }
    }
    if(($parts["host"]=="youtu.be" || $parts["host"]=="www.youtu.be") && isset($parts['path'])){
        $path = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));
        return $path[count($path)-1];
    }
    }
    if(strlen($url)==11 && (!strstr($url, "http://") && !strstr($url, "https://") && !strstr($url, "www.") && !strstr($url, "youtube") && !strstr($url, "www.") && !strstr($url, "youtu.be"))) return $url;
    return false;
}

function validateFbVideoUrl($url){
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if(($parts["host"]=="facebook.com" || $parts["host"]=="www.facebook.com" || $parts["host"]=="fb.me" || $parts["host"]=="fb.com") && !strstr($url,"/pg/")){
        return $url;
    }
    return false;
}

function getVimeoId($url){
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if($parts['host'] == 'www.vimeo.com' || $parts['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){
        $vidid=substr($parts['path'], 1);
        return $vidid;
    }
    return false;
}

function getvidinfo($url){
     $getYT=getYoutubeIdFromUrl($url);
     if($getYT){
        $result["type"]="yt";
        $result["string"]=$getYT;
        $result["img"]="https://img.youtube.com/vi/".$getYT."/mqdefault.jpg";
        return($result);
     }else{
         //fb video
         $getFB=validateFbVideoUrl($url);
         if($getFB){
            $result["type"]="fb";
            $result["string"]=$getFB;
            $result["img"]="example.com/your-image-here.jpg";// I DIDN'T FIND A WAY TO GET FB VIDEO THUMBNAIL
            return($result);
         }else{
             $vimeoid=getVimeoId($url);
             if($vimeoid){
                $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$vimeoid.php"));
                $result["type"]="vim";
                $result["string"]=$vimeoid;
                $result["img"]=$hash[0]["thumbnail_large"];
                return($result);
             }
         }
    }
    return false;
}

function echovideo($url){
    if($url){
        $vidinfo=getvidinfo($url);
        if($vidinfo){
            if($vidinfo["type"]=="yt"){
            ?><div>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<?echo $vidinfo["string"]?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <?
            }elseif($vidinfo["type"]=="fb"){
                ?>
                <div>
                 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=<? echo $vidinfo["string"]; ?>&show_text=0&width=560&height=315" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe></div>
                 <?
            }elseif($vidinfo["type"]=="vim"){
                ?><div><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?echo $vimeoid;?>" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <?
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Simple usage:

```
echovideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRuL3_5rFnU");
```